# How can delegate Access Token acquisition to a BFF?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

There is a several options on how to secure access to resource APIs from clients(web/mobile...), And in recent years, it was common to implement OIDC for SPAs in JS / TS, and this is no longer recommended.

The recommendation for SPA is to avoid storing tokens in the browser Or using service worker, And use a BFF insted of direct connect to Identity Server.

In this approach the BFF works as proxy of Identity Server and handle all oauth requests.

What is the best practice to implement this pattern with spring BFF, Or if there is another better approach.

Comment: so did you find an implementation?

Comment: @usertest see my answer below, I wrote an article for that: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're aware of [this doc](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#name-application-architecture-pa) which explains the options. Assuming you are using an SPA and don't want the website option, there are 2 options, identical from a security viewpoint, and which you use is a matter of preference.

**WEB BACKEND**

The SPA sends OAuth and API requests to a web backend first, which forwards them and implements the OAuth client. The web backend uses a runtime that issues cookies.

Pros are an easier initial developer setup and fewer components to deploy. Cons are that all developers have to run the backend, and web deployment options are limited to those that can host the runtime.

**REVERSE PROXY BACKEND**

The SPA sends OAuth and API requests via a reverse proxy such as NGINX. OAuth requests are forwarded to a utility API. The web backend remains static content only.

Pros are that you can get rid of the cookie issuing runtime from a developer PC, and it is easier to do things like deploy web resources to a content delivery network. Cons are that the initial developer setup is harder and that there are more moving parts.

**BEHAVIOR**

In both cases the SPA uses URLs like this, for static content, oauth client and API routing responsibilities.

- https://www.example.com
- https://www.example.com/oauth-client
- https://www.example.com/api

Within the oauth-client path, the SPA calls endpoints like this. The SPA OAuth code is very light:

- POST /login/start
- POST /login/end

**IMPLEMENTATIONS**

There are quite a few out there, including components you can plug in. Search for a term like `BFF OAuth` and do some reading. It is a journey though - cookies are complicated little things.

Comment: Thanks, Already know this approach. Can you share some implementations or ready components to use, might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added [a tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) on one of my repos for configuring `spring-cloud-gateway` as BFF between a browser application secured with sessions (Secure HttpOnly cookie) and an OAuth2 resource-server.

This sample uses Angular as UI framework, a thin wrapper of mine around `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`, and Keycloak as authorization-server, but this are implementations details are all the work is done by the BFF.

##### Edit: [My tutorial is now on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2)